# Effectively universal Turing machines and Turing-completeness?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem, turing-completeness

An effectively universal Turing machine $T$ is a Turing machine for which there exists a recursive reduction $f$ such that $\forall A:U(A)=T(f(A))$, where $A, f(A)$ are finite sequences of symbols (that are given as inputs) and $U$ is a universal Turing machine.

Is there any connection between effectively universal Turing machines and Turing-completeness?

Also, given a Turing machine $T$ that is *not* effectively universal, is it possible to decide if it halts on a specific input? As far as I am aware, the diagonalization argument would not apply, since the TM used in the construction would be effectively universal.

My attempt so far was to use an argument from contradiction:

> If this variant of halting problem is undecidable, then there exists a recursive reduction from the (general) halting problem to it. However, if such a reduction exists, it contradicts the premise that $T$ is not effectively universal.

I am not sure, however, if this is correct or if it misses anything.

Comment: You seem to be missing some "for all $A,B$" somewhere.  Please [edit] the question to clarify the first sentence and place the quantifiers in the correct place.  Also, what are $A,B$?  Also, what does "$T$ behave on $B$" mean?   Can you make the definition more precise?